# android layout leaving small gaps

Tags: android, android-layout

So I have a image view and below a relative layout. The desired is to always have the users see the text views and buttons in the nested layout. And the image is a top image ( not a full screen background) but some how there is a small gap and the background of the image is bleed past the image view. I have tried different Image scale types and different layouts completely(frame, all linear,etc..)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcX9b.jpg

and some code

https://gist.github.com/whatkai/92f66d2322957d86dd3fe28a9a5d03c0

FYI layout-weights left gaps too.

Answer (score 0):

There is too many ways to do it.
Try this solution using LinearLayout (orientation: vertical):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/REFragment"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/accidentAssistanceColor">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/SettingsImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/ers"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:background="@color/appStartERSBackground"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/onView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/SettingsImage"
    android:gravity="bottom|clip_vertical|center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:text="Not Now"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/button"
        android:text="approve"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    <TextView
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/button2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="BLdfdsAH"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>


    <TextView
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="BLAH"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And to answer you about how to scall your image i used android:scaleType fitXY to respect to ratio aspet.

If you desire to understand how every scallType works, see the following link:
https://robots.thoughtbot.com/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide

Comment: this was similar to my first attempt but it still gives my device a small gap ? unknown still to why the layouts don't seem to snap in place

Comment: can you please join a screenshot of what do you need?

Answer (score 0):

set view tag between your image and layout.
like this.

```
 <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#000000" />
```